# How to detect all changes from a transaction on a model, that makes multiple updates, and that uses after_commit hook to fire on commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

I'm currently trying to create a cache update after a transaction is complete in a ruby service file, that is conditional on the fields that were updated by using the `saved_change_to_attributes` method to check which fields were just updated. But the previous_changes caught are only those of the last update called within that transaction.

Is there a way to check for all previous changes within that transaction from that callback method after the commit is finished?

```
/comment_service.rb
class CommentService < ApplicationService
  def submit
    ...

    comment.transaction do
      comment.update!(is_submitted: true)

      if condition
        user.update!(author: true)
      end
    end

  end
end

---

/comment.rb

class Comment < ApplicationRecord

  after_commit :update_counter_caches

  def update_count_caches
    ...
    if saved_change_to_is_submitted?
      (do something)
    end
  end
end
```

The issue being that the method `saved_change_to_is_submitted` returns nil and the only previous_changes caught from the transaction are the keys from the last update, this example being `author`. So some code isn't being ran even though those values were just updated. I'm not sure how to include the previous updates in with the previous_changes from the transaction.

Comment: Can you add some code snippet to better understand the context/question? Do you want to record multiple updates within the same transaction of a single attribute?

Comment: I made the update. Hopefully that's enough to help. If not please let me know. 

And exactly, and to be able to check those changes from the callback method from the model

Comment: I think you mean `after_commit` and not `after_comment`.

Comment: Yes, good catch. I do mean after_commit. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Do you really need to use a callback here? The main advantage of a service is that you can control exactly when your logic is fired.

Comment: This was written to make sure we update the cache whenever there is a change to the data. I'm couldn't say if thats the best way to handle that

Comment: I think it won't be possible to get the previous changes before the last save with the `saved_change_to_attribute` method. As the doc clearly says, it returns the change to an attribute during the last save. What u can do is to maintain an array of change list inside the transaction and return the change list array from the service. U can then  use the array inside `update_count_caches` method.

Comment: why do you need to check it at all? If you're updating a cache, just dumping the latest value should suffice.